# Bounded linear space (elementary question)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Does exist  (nonzero) bounded normed space over any field?

Fix normed linear space $L$ over field K.
We have $x+x+x+\cdots\in L$
So $||nx||=n||x||\rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty \\$ 
Is this ok?
Is zero space bounded normed space?

Answer (score 1):

In  general, $\|nx\| = n \|x\|$ can't work.  In the case of a field of nonzero characteristic, there are only finitely many different values for $n x$.

Comment: Ok, Thank You.  So how proof this or it sentence is false?

Comment: Usually, norms are only defined for vector spaces over subfields of $\mathbb C$.  But you can have metrizable topological linear spaces over other fields, and these can be bounded.  For example, take $\mathbb F^d$ for a finite field $\mathbb F$.